# Type Incompatibility

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that returns the mode of an array (I'm not asking how to make the method and would rather you not give me any ideas. For those of you who keep criticizing my questions for being repeats of others, I know that the answer is already on this website. That's not the question). I made a method, in a class called BasicMathMethods, called getTotal:

```
public static int getTotal(double[] a, int b)
{
    int count = 0;
    int Element;
    for(Element = 0; Element < a.length; Element++)
    {
        if(a[b] == a[Element])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And I tried to use this method in my mode method:

```
 public static double Mode(double[] a)
{
    for(int element = 0; element < a.length; element++)
    {
        int[] largest = BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, element);// gets the count of each element
        Arrays.sort(largest);
        if(BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, element) == largest.length)
        return a[element];
    }
}
```

However, my compiler (which is Blue J by the way) says "Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]", and highlights (a, element). I don't understand the error. I don't see where I am trying to convert int[] to int. Could anyone tell me what the error is and explain?

Comment: Your code is full of style attrocities.  1) Never start the name of a local variable with a capital letter.  2) Never start the name of a method with a capital letter.  3) Use consistent indentation.

Comment: Sorry that my code disturbs you...I'm a beginner.

Comment: If you would have googled the exception, you would have seen that you cannot store an `int` in a variable that is declared as an `int array`.

Comment: *I'm a beginner* - That's why I am telling you. So that you will learn!  In the Java world, ignoring the style rules is similar to writing English while ignoring the rules of grammar, punctuation and spelling. It is irritating for the reader, and liable to lead to people misreading what you have written.

Comment: Well thanks for telling me Stephen C. I will take your advice seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the value you get from `BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, element)` to an array, there are a few complications. You don't know how many values you will get. Therefore, you will not be able to know the required size of the array.

Use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array.

**But more importantly. I would like to point out major issues with your approach to obtain the `mode`. Read over the code below to see if it makes sense.**

```
public static double mode(double[] a) {

    double currentBestCandidate = a[0];
    int countCurrentBestCandidate = BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, 0);

    // we already have index 0, lets start from 1
    for(int element = 1; element < a.length; element++) {
        int count = BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, element);

        // if this count is greater than what we have 
        // right now, we need to update currentBestCandidate 
        // and countCurrentBestCandidate
        if(count > countCurrentBestCandidate) {
            currentBestCandidate = a[element];
            countCurrentBestCandidate = count;
        }
    }
    return currentBestCandidate;
}
```

Comment: I see. This is very clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You return an int from getTotal and are trying to put it into an int[] variable.

```
int[] largest = BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, element);
```

The return type of getTotal is `int`

```
public static int getTotal(double[] a, int b)
```

Comment: I was thinking that it was supposed to be an array of integers, which is why I put int[] largest = BasicMathMethods.getTotal(a, element). I wanted it to add the integers to the array. How would I do that?

Comment: You should read this.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html  Among other things, it shows you how to put an integer into an array.